# LibGDX GDX-Pay crash

Tags: java, android, libgdx, gdx-pay

I implement the GDXPay but if i want to start the Game it comes a crash with this value

> 10-15 04:40:42.963 1721-1721/com.packagename.mygame.android E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.badlogic.gdx.pay.PurchaseManagerConfig com.packagename.mygame.mygame.purchaseManagerConfig' on a null object reference
>   10-15 04:40:42.963 1721-1721/com.packagename.mygame.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.packagename.mygame.android.GooglePlayResolver.(GooglePlayResolver.java:17)
>   10-15 04:40:42.963 1721-1721/com.packagename.mygame.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.packagename.mygame.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:42)

I don't understand it. I hope you can help me.

Comment: i think posting the relvent code where you integrated GDXPAY could make it easy to point out the error

Comment: i do the same like this tutorial: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/wiki/Integration-example-with-resolvers

Comment: the debug log say com.packagename.mygame.mygame.purchaseManagerConfig is a null referenz but why ? i import the libary

Comment: few things that come to my mind is u didnt register the activity(if there is any) in the manifest or didnt exported the jar

Comment: its a attemt. how i register the activity in the manifest ?

Comment: i am sorry i read the documentation u dont need to registerany activity as there is none, sorry again

Comment: no problem but you have a another idea ?

Comment: i think i import the libary corect but i dont understand how this fault comes.

Comment: if u did the steps correctly then it should work, it works fine for me in my projects ( my team memebers did that i still have to import for me)

Comment: i did the steps out of a little parts

Comment: or you can send me your libary and i import that :)

Comment: i dont want to get fired for sending company code, my boss is pretty active here, he consider open source code also as his own property

Comment: ok i understand this. 
But i hope you have a antoher idea for my problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92464/discussion-between-kumar-saurabh-and-wiifree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a other answer. GDX Pay dont work so good but with this tutorial it work good. [LINK](http://pipplo.com/?p=62)

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks for sharing this